# mongodb log4j2 authentication failed

Tags: java, mongodb, log4j2

I'm trying to set up log4j's NoSQL appended to work with MongoDB, but I'm having trouble authenticating with my newly created account.

I created the following user with:

```js
use admin
db.createUser({
  user: "loguser1",
  pwd: "logpassword",
  roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]
})
```

And, I can connect using:

```js
mongo - u loguser1 - p logpassword
```

But, when log4j2 attempts to connect, I get the following error in mongod:

```js
2015-03-31T13:08:24.137-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63098 #9 (2 connections now open)
2015-03-31T13:08:24.161-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:63099 #10 (3 connections now open)
2015-03-31T13:08:24.166-0500 I ACCESS   [conn10]  authenticate db: test { authenticate: 1, user: "loguser1", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
2015-03-31T13:08:24.167-0500 I ACCESS   [conn10] Failed to authenticate loguser1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
2015-03-31T13:08:25.410-0500 I NETWORK  [conn10] end connection 127.0.0.1:63099 (2 connections now open)
2015-03-31T13:08:25.411-0500 I NETWORK  [conn9] end connection 127.0.0.1:63098 (2 connections now open)
```

And here is my (snippet of a properly formatted) log4j2.yml:

```js
Configuration:
  status: info
  
  Appenders:
 NoSql:
      name: Mongo
      MongoDb:
        databaseName: test
        server: localhost
        username: loguser1
        password: logpassword
```

I must be doing something silly, I'm hoping one of you can spot it. Thanks for looking!

EDIT: I spent some more time banging my head against the keyboard, and tried rolling back to MongoDb 2.6.9 (I had been trying to use 3.0), and took my time configuring an admin and user account (http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) and it appears to be working. I'm not 100% positive, but I'm not sure if log4j2 works as stated above with MongoDB 3.0 (Or, possibly, I hosed up my user accounts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > 2015-03-31T13:08:24.167-0500 I ACCESS   [conn10] Failed to authenticate loguser1@test with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document

Note that although the user credentials are stored in **admin** database, you log in to **test** database (default database when none is specified).

You can do one of the following things:

Create a new user with same roles in the **test** database:

```
use test
db.createUser({
    user: "loguser2",
    pwd: "logpassword",
    roles: ["readWrite", "dbAdmin"]
})
```

And login with that username (*loguser2*)

Alternatively, you can grant the user **readWriteAnyDatabase** role in **admin** database:

```
use admin
db.createUser({
    user: "loguser3",
    pwd: "logpassword",
    roles: ["readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdmin"]
})
```

and specify **authenticationDatabase** when connecting (as *loguser3*)

```
mongo -u loguser3 -p logpassword --authenticationDatabase admin
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
```

Comment: Looking at your answer, and what I did the 2nd time I configured the database, I'm assured that you're correct. The user I was trying to authenticate as wasn't in that database. Marking as solved, thanks!